# How to enable object permanence / tracking with ARKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I've built an ultra-simple AR app in Swift (expanding on the template) to display 3D models on image anchors. But when an image anchor goes out of frame, the attached models disappear – they reload the next time the anchor is detected.

It'd be a much better experience if the models persisted as users pan around. How can I enable object permanence?

My code:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load scenes 
        let OneAnchor = try! One.loadFace()
        let TwoAnchor = try! Two.loadFace()
        let ThreeAnchor = try! Three.loadFace()
        let FourAnchor = try! Four.loadFace()

        // Add anchors
        arView.scene.anchors.append(OneAnchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(TwoAnchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(ThreeAnchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(FourAnchor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For persistence you need to use [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration) class with `.detectionImages` instance property instead of [ARImageTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration) class.

Here's what official documentation says:

> `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` can create immersive AR experiences: A virtual object can appear to stay in the same place relative to the real world, even as the user tilts the device to look above or below the object, or moves the device around to see the object's sides and back.

Your code inside `viewWillAppear(animated)` life cycle method might look like this:

```
label.text = "Track your environment"

guard let refImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Pictures", 
                                                             bundle: nil)
else { 
    return 
}

let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
config.detectionImages = refImages
config.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 4

let options = [ARSession.RunOptions.removeExistingAnchors,
               ARSession.RunOptions.resetTracking]

arView.session.run(config, options: ARSession.RunOptions(options))
```